# how Can I find out if the current user has access to a record on clicking button on my object by using lightning flow?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, user, userrecordaccess, lightning-flow-builder

how Can I find out if the current user has access to a record on clicking button on my object by using lightning flow ?

there is a custom button configured on object , on click of that button i want to check that user has access of that record or not , this needs to done by lightning flow.
is someone have any idea about it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below in flow :-

1. Query on the object userrecordacess object by passing record id and user id to check if the user has edit excess
2. Haseditacess will determine his ability to edit

For more information, Refer this link [Learn About UserRecordAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm)